# How to get SelectedDataKey value in the GridView RowCommand Event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have one Gridview like this.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvMRLSearch" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                CssClass="datagrid" DataKeyNames="MRLID" >
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="MRLID" HeaderText="MRL ID" Visible="false" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="MRLCreateDate" HeaderText="MRL Create Date" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="MRLNumber" HeaderText="MRL Number" />   
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="printReport" Text="Print" HeaderText="Action" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to Get the MRLID value on the GridView_RowCommand Event.
I have tried like this:

```
protected void gvMRLSearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
       if (e.CommandName == "printReport")
       {
         int MRLID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMRLSearch.SelectedDataKey.Value);
```

But I get only the first row MRLID only, if selects the second again I get the first row MRLID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
if (e.CommandName == "printReport")
        {
            int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int MRLID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMRLSearch.DataKeys[rowindex].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you call RowCommand event handler , it will not change the selected row of grid

set SelectedIndex property of the grid